# How to determine Depedent and Span of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$ \displaystyle  s=  (2,4,6)^T ,(0,0,0)^T ,(0,1,1)^T \in  R^3 $

Does S are dependent linear?

Does S are Span of $R^3$ ?

Comment: Solve a system of linear equations to see if given $(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3$, you can alwats find scalars $\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma$ such that $(x,y,z)=\alpha (2,4,6)+\beta (0,0,0)+\gamma (0,1,1)$. Alternatively consider the matrix whose columns are the given vectors, compute the determinant and with whatever you get, conclude something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set of vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n$ is said to be linearly independent if

$$\alpha_1\mathbf{v}_1+\alpha_2\mathbf{v}_2+\ldots+\alpha_n\mathbf{v}_n=\mathbf{0} \iff \alpha_1=\alpha_2=\ldots=\alpha_n=0;$$

otherwise, it is linearly dependent.

In your case, we have to find the solutions to

$$\alpha_1(2,4,6)+\alpha_2(0,0,0)+\alpha_3(0,1,1)=(0,0,0).$$

Clearly, the equation is satisfied by $\alpha_1=\alpha_3=0$, $\alpha_2\in\mathbb{R}$, so the condition is false and the set is linearly dependent.

It also follows that the set cannot span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, since there are at most two linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Any set of vectors containing the zero vector is linearly dependent.